# How to store historic time series data

Tags: mysql, amazon-s3, time-series, hdf5, influxdb

we're storing a bunch of time series data from several measurement devices.
All devices may provide different dimensions (energy, temp, etc.)

Currently we're using MySQL to store all this data in different tables (according to the dimension) in the format
  idDevice, DateTime, val1, val2, val3

We're also aggregating this data from min -> Hour -> Day -> Month -> Year each time we insert new data

This is running quite fine, but we're running out of disk space as we are growing and in general I doubt that a RDBMS is the right answer to keep archive data.

So we're thinking of moving old/cold data on Amazon S3 and write some fancy getter that can recieve this data.

So here my question comes: what could be a good data format to support the following needs:

The data must be extensible in terms: once i a while a device will provide more data, then in the past -> the count of rows can grow/increase

The data must be updated. When a customer delivers historic data, we need to be able to update that for the past.

We're using PHP -> would be nice to have connectors/classes :)

I've had a look on HDF5, but it seems there is no PHP lib.
We're also willing to have a look on cloud based TimeSeries Databases.

Thank you in advance!
B

Comment: How much data do you have?  Disk space is not particularly expensive these days.

Comment: Currently we're about to reach 1TB but our forecast seems to reach 4TB within the next year.
Our objective would also be to scale the data on a cloud service like S3

Answer (score 1):

You might consider moving to a dedicated time-series database. I work for InfluxDB and our product meets most of your requirements right now, although it is still pre-1.0 release.

> We're also aggregating this data from min -> Hour -> Day -> Month -> Year each time we insert new data

InfluxDB has built-in tools to automatically downsample and expire data. All you do is write the raw points and set up a few queries and retention policies, InfluxDB handles the rest internally.

> The data must be extensible in terms: once i a while a device will provide more data, then in the past -> the count of rows can grow/increase

As long as historic writes are fairly infrequent they are no problem for InfluxDB. If you are frequently writing in non-sequential data the write performance can slow down, but only while the non-sequential points are being replicated.

InfluxDB is not quite schema-less, but the schema cannot be pre-defined, and is derived from the points inserted. You can add new tags (metadata) or fields (metrics) simply by writing a new point that includes them, and you can automatically compose or decompose series by excluding or including the relevant tags when querying.

> The data must be updated. When a customer delivers historic data, we need to be able to update that for the past.

InfluxDB silently overwrites points when a new matching point comes in. (Matching means same series and timestamp, to the nanosecond)

> We're using PHP -> would be nice to have connectors/classes :)

There are a handful of PHP libraries out there for InfluxDB 0.9. None are officially supported but likely one fits your needs enough to extend or fork.

Comment: We already have looked at InfluxDB but it lacks several main features as there are:

 * robust and production prooven clustering (current clusters are said to be alpha)
 * sharding. currently all data is within 1 huge database. once in a while this will exceed IOPS as well as storage capacity

Comment: All very valid reasons to hold off. Clustering is projected to be production-ready in early Q4 of this year.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't specified what you want enough.

**Do you care about latency?** If not, just write all your data points to per-interval files in S3, then periodically collect them and process them. (No Hadoop needed, just a simple script downloading the new files should usually be plenty fast enough.)  This is how logging in S3 works.

The really nice part about this is you will never outgrow S3 or do any maintenance. If you prefix your files correctly, you can grab a day's worth of data or the last hour of data easily. Then you do your day/week/month roll-ups on that data, then store only the roll-ups in a regular database.

**Do you need the old data at high resolution?** You can use Graphite to roll-up your data automatically. The downside is that it looses resolution as you age. But the upside is that your data is a fixed size and never grows, and writes can be handled quickly.  You can even combine the above approach and send data to Graphite for quick viewing, but keep the data in S3 for other uses down the road.

I haven't researched the various TSDBs extensively, but here is a nice [HN thread](https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=8368509) about it.  InfluxDB is nice, but new. Cassandra is more mature, but the tooling to use it as a TSB isn't all there yet.

**How much new data do you have?** Most tools will handle 10,000 datapoints per second easily, but not all of them can scale beyond that.

Comment: tnx for your answer.

For historic data we do not really care about latency. Basically we're also thinking of storing our data in plain S3 files.
One of my questions would be: what is a good extensible data format for storing timeseries data within files? The data we recieved comes from various vendors and all of them have different data formats (CSV,XML,json) -> we're already preprocessing this -> but how to store it? currently we prcoess it in the CSV format the database has, but whenever we do a schema update, all the old CSV files are no longer valid.

Comment: There is no simple answer for that. One helpful idea is to label the schema version of each file. Then your importer can say "oh, for v1 schema we need to create a dummy field here". But there is no magic that takes care of it for you.

Answer (score 0):

I'm with the team that develops [Axibase Time-Series Database](https://axibase.com/docs/atsd/). It's a non-relational database that allows you to efficiently store timestamped measurements with various dimensions. You can also store device properties (id, location, type, etc) in the same database for filtering and grouped aggregations.

ATSD doesn't delete raw data by default. Each sample takes 3.5+ bytes per tuple: `time:value`. Period aggregations are performed at request time and the list of functions includes: MIN, MAX, AVG, SUM, COUNT, PERCENTILE(n), STANDARD_DEVIATION, FIRST, LAST, DELTA, RATE, WAVG, WTAVG as well as some some additional functions for computing threshold violations per period.

Backfilling historical data is fully supported except that the timestamp has to be greater than January 1, 1970. Time precision is milliseconds or seconds.

As for deployment options, you could host this database on AWS. It runs on most Linux distributions. We could run some storage efficiency and throughput tests for you if you want to post sample data from your dataset here.

Comment: what about clustering / sharding?

Comment: ATSD uses HBase for raw storage so both throughput and storage capacity is scaled by adding nodes (aka regionservers). In a fully distributed installation data is replicated 3 times for fault-tolerance but you can also configure master-slave replication: https://axibase.com/products/axibase-time-series-database/download-atsd/administration/atsd-replication/